# My XML is being served as XHTML

Tags: php, xml, xhtml

I'm making a sitemap for search engine crawlers, and I came across a problem.

Google allows multilingual sitemaps by adding alternate XHTML tags for other languages, as follows:

`<xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="http://example.org/" />`

To do this, I have to add an xhtml namespace in my urlset. However, when I do this, my XML is no longer being served as XML, but as XHTML. It looks fine when viewing the source code, but the browser still won't recognize it as an XML document.

Example PHP code:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">       
    <url>
        <loc>http://example.com</loc>
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en_US" href="http://example.net" />
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="http://example.org/" />
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="zh_CN" href="http://example.edu/" />
    </url>
</urlset>
XML;

header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo $xml;
```

If I alter the URL of the xhtml namespace slightly (Like adding a slash), the browser will once again recognize the file as XML, but Google will no longer accept it. Changing the header Content-Type to application/xml doesn't work, either.

This issue happens in Internet Explorer, Firefox and Chrome alike.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all you should understand that xhtml **IS** xml: it is just specific XML schema applied to XML document.

Your issue that browser you use recognizes attributes you use and decides that it is better to show it as rendered page instead of generic XML layout. Adding slash as you did indeed breaks the attribute and so browser decides that it sees some generic XML instead of xhtml page. Google of course validates inbound xml and is unhappy that it is malformed.

Your attempt to change content-type is plausible (and you should keep it) but browsers rely on multiple places which tell them HOW to display the document. Content-type probably is too low in precedence and is overriden.

I believe if you use <!DOCTYPE definition in your xml stating that it is xml document and not html then browser may be convinced to display it differently. Google will ignore <!DOCTYPE declaration as a comment.

If <!DOCTYPE is not declared in your document then browser is free to select document type as it see fits and that what you observe.